# python-pptx: New text box text starts on line 2 with first line being blank... cannot solve

Tags: powerpoint, python-pptx

Help!

Love the package. No issues except the following one -- creating a text frame in a shape with the following:

```py
       text = text_small
       text_frame = box.text_frame
       text_frame.paragraphs[0].space_after = Pt(0)
       p = text_frame.add_paragraph()
       p.clear()
       p.text = "TODO"
       p.font.size = Pt(12)
       p.alignment = 1  # Center alignment
       p.font.name = font_name
       p.font.bold = True
       p.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
```

However, no matter what I try the text ends up on line 2 of the text frame with an empty line above it.

The following is what i've tried so far that has not helped...

```py
       text_frame.paragraphs[0].space_after = Pt(0)
       p = text_frame.add_paragraph()
       p.clear()
```

Here are links to photos of the PPT.

https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/assets/7648723/5ec496ea-f3d3-4af4-936b-c8b719a7d2de

https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/assets/7648723/c0dfedd4-e2f3-48b7-ae8b-a4ed335ae7b8

Answer (score 1):

A text frame is born with a single empty paragraph. So you put your text there then only add a new paragraph if you need another. Per: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/918